# Adding extra url query string to @Html.PagedListPager aside page in ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am PagedList for pagination when collecting values to my web page through ajax. The ajax call works well but When I click on the pagination links to display other details of the report for other pages, I have no value returned because I am adding extra parameters to the @Html.PagedListPager  method aside the page used in the action method.
I am returning values through my partial views. The problem is how to add the extra

parameters to the pagination link.

My partial view code is below

```
    @using Microsoft.Security.Application
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

@model IPagedList<LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Models.Livechat.Chatreportview>

@{
    var FromDate = ViewBag.FromDate; //values to be added to pagination link
    var ToDate = ViewBag.ToDate; //values to be added to pagination link
}


@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="numlinks">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DisplayAllchatreport",
 new { FromDate = FromDate, ToDate = ToDate, page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true })
    </div>
}
```

Please focus on the bottom part of the code, cause that is were the problem lies adding the ViewBag values to be part of the url so the pargination link is clicked other details can be returned.

Comment: Can you clarify what the exact problem is? Are the extra query params not showing up in the URL for the link?

Comment: They are not showing at all

Comment: I only see the ?page=  show. extras dont show. I have been on it for 2 days now

Comment: Are you sure that `FromDate` and `ToDate` are not null?

Comment: ok I am checking for that you may be right.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, You are right does values are null. I just did a debug. They are empty values.

Comment: I am trying to fix the null issue now

Answer (score 0):

FromDate and ToDate values were null. So I edited my controller and passed this values into the model which I was sending into my partialView.
So this allowed me to use them in my pagination links in the partialView

Answer (score 0):

use Request to manage

```
  fromDate = Request.QueryString["fromDate"]
   //...
```